# SSL certificate for non 443 port

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have Googled a lot but cannot find proper information.

If I have a wildcard SSL certificate for say ABC.com can I use it for non 443 ports?

Eg.
https://d1.abc.com:4430

Comment: Yes. The certificate doesn't have any port information in it. You didn't provide a port number anywhere to the signer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. A certificate only contains the domain names it is valid for: not any ports.